# CSS scroll snap triggering on something other than scroll

Tags: css

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-wood-0bikbb?file=/src/styles.css

To replicate:

- focus the input at the top
- scroll all the way to the bottom, click on an empty space
- notice that the screen jumps back up to the top to the snap target

What I've determined seems to be contributing to this:

- The scroll window being ontop of a space with no snap target in proximity
- The input width being resized on focus/blur

What the demo does:

- On focus/blur of the input, a class is attached/removed from the container element.
- That class changes the width of the container
- The input container is the only element with `scroll-snap-align` set.

**Question: what is causing this jump to occur, and how do I stop it?**

Comment: i am not able to see jump from bottom to top in given fiddle. Can you please check and update it with issue in action?

Comment: @Leothelion, it may be because you are not using a chromium based browser, which Sheraff identified as the browser with the bug in the answer.

Comment: @Sheraff, apologies I thought I pressed it when I marked the answer correct. I also think it would have auto given it to you anyway as the correct answer. Thank you again!

Comment: you did not mention in your question thats why but now got it. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have stumbled onto a chromium bug. Nowadays they are a little less common, but still not that rare. We tend to find them in the edge-cases of new(-ish) features and there is no other choice but to work around them.

Here's the minimal reproducible example, which replicates your issue in Chrome, but not in Safari nor Firefox (macOS).

```css
.main {
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  background: green;
}

.spacer {
  height: 200%;
}

input {
  width: 25%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

input:focus {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to be a good citizen of the web, your next step would be to check on the chromium bug tracker whether that bug has been reported already or not, and if needed file an issue yourself https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

---

As for your practical case of what to do to avoid it? As long as it is not fixed you'll need to find a workaround. This could include (not tested but likely to work):

- only enabling scroll snapping under certain conditions (pretty standard workaround for other scroll-snap related issues chrome has had for the past few years)
- force the scroll position on input blur
- don't resize the input
- add a snap target below the input
- change your design / functional requirements

Comment: Thank you @Sheraff great response despite it being unfortunate and thank you for including a reduced example. Will mark as answer if none others highlight a fix before bounty expires.

Do you mind expanding on your first workaround? Do you mean something like disabling scroll snap if something is being focused?

I also think adding a snap target is a great workaround.

Comment: @rbhalla my first point is something I had to do for a website I worked on a couple years ago: a horizontal slideshow with scroll snapping was being scrolled into view when its images loaded (which caused a resize of the slides). The solution I found at the time was to disable scroll snapping as long as the slideshow wasn't in the viewport. I'm not exactly sure how that could apply to your exact situation... but hopefully one of these suggestions leads you to a good solution.